# Table populated by scriptlet code not displaying

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, scriptlet

I have a table in a web page that is populated by scriptlet code. I've only been introduced to this code base for about a month, and new to working in JSPs, MVC framework, etc. This web application was also written in the early 2000s, so as one would expect, many things are broken. One thing that puzzles me is this table:

```
  <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="480">

<%
    for ( int i=0; i< fds.size(); i++)
    {
        FreqDeptInfo                fdi     =   (FreqDeptInfo)fds.elementAt(i);

%>
        <tr class="<%=(i%2 == 0)? "row": "row1"%>"  id="<%=i%>" onclick="userclickhandler(this, <%=i%>)" ONDBLCLICK="parent.editTollFreeCodeHandler(form1)" onkeydown="upDown(event, form1)">
            <td width="175" align="left" class="smalltext"><%=ApplicationBean.escapeHTML(ApplicationBean.getDetailedName(fdi.sDeptName))%></td>
            <td width="130" align="left" class="smalltext"><%=ApplicationBean.escapeHTML(ApplicationBean.getEntitySite(fdi.sDeptName))%></td>
            <td width="80" align="left" class="smalltext"><%=ApplicationBean.escapeHTML(ApplicationBean.getFormattedDeptFrequency(fdi.dProbability))%></td>
        </tr>
<%
    }
%>

  </table>
```

To be honest, I haven't any idea what the scriptlet code is doing, all I know is that this for loop is populating the table. Without knowing exactly what the servlet is doing, is there any obvious reason why the table remains unpopulated when inspected in the browser?

Comment: i think `fds` is empty .Did you print and see that ? does it has any value?

Comment: I omitted the initialization of ```fds```, I'm just sort of puzzled that not even the ```<tr>``` tag shows up in the DOM.

Comment: yes because `fds` is empty so it will not go inside `for-loop` and will not print any html which is inside it .

Comment: Ah interesting, I will investigate this.